# Finding inverse Z Transform

Tags: z-transform

Find the inverse Z transform:

[image]

I have done the solution but my answer does not match with the one given in the textbook. What I may have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find $\frac{X(z)}{U(z)}$ ?.

Comment: @Cesareo I am trying to find x[n].